# Convert nested hash-tables to a-list how to ensure the creation dotted pairs

Tags: common-lisp, cons

I wrote the following function to convert nested hash-tables to an a-list:

```
(defun hash-table->alist* (ht)
  (loop for k being the hash-keys in ht using (hash-value v)
        collect (cons k
                      (etypecase v
                        (integer v)
                        (hash-table (hash-table->alist* v))))))
```

It works fine for non nested hash-tables:

```
> (hash-table->alist* (dict :a 1 :b 23 :c 4))
((:A . 1) (:B . 23) (:C . 4))
```

But when I use it on nested hash-tables I loose the dotted-pairs on the way:

```
> (hash-table->alist* (dict :session (dict :user (dict :fullname 23))))
((:SESSION (:USER (:FULLNAME . 23))))
```

How can I ensure the creation of a dotted pair instead of appending to the front of a list?

Comment: in your `(K . V)` pair here the value `V` is a list, which is NOT printed with a dot; however, you still have the right structure

Comment: You are right. I have been looking for a non existent problem for the whole time.

Comment: FWIW I disagree with the close reason because it is not a typo, it is a peculiarity of Lisp that is often confusing to people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you expected:

```lisp
((:SESSION . ((:USER . ((:FULLNAME . 23))))))
```

However, if the cdr of a cons cell contains a list, this implies a list structure, which is printed without dot and without nested parentheses.  This is how lists are defined: `(A . (B))` *is* `(A B)`.  So, this is exactly the same structure:

```lisp
((:SESSION (:USER (:FULLNAME . 23))))
```

This confusion is unavoidable, because the fact that a given list structure is *meant* as an alist is not possible to discern from the structure itself.